# Strange! Right solution of equation is partially wrong.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $0<a<1$ be arbitrary but fixed. The equation
$$ \frac{x^2 (1+y)^2}{\left(a y + \sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}\right)^2} = 1$$

in $y$ has according to straight-forward calculus and *Mathematica* two solutions 
$$y = \frac{1-x^2}{(x \pm a)^2}.$$

But plugging them into the **left side** of the equation and plotting as a function of $x$ reveals that they are only partially right (should be constant $1$)!

[[image: Plot for <span class=]$a=0.75$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPYE.png)

There is no reason for this restriction during calculation. What the hell is going on here?

Comment: Looks $x=\pm1$ makes $y=0$ ?

Comment: $y=-1$ is not a solution as it makes the left hand side undefined

Comment: Yes, $(\pm 1,0)$ is one solution point.

Comment: Okay, the eqn. was originally not written as a fraction, then $-1$ is a solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What restriction?  What do the graphs mean?

Comment: The graphs show the proposed two solutions inserted into the left side of the equation as a function $y = f(x)$. It should be constant $1$ but is not.

Comment: What do you mean inserting the solutions an ploting as $y=f(x)$.  You hae the equations $\frac{x^2 (1+\frac{1-x^2}{(x \pm a)^2})^2}{\left(a \frac{1-x^2}{(x \pm a)^2} + \sqrt{1+(1-a^2)\frac{1-x^2}{(x \pm a)^2}}\right)^2} = 1$.  What does plotting *that* as "$y=f(x)"$.

Comment: Right, and now just plot the left side as a function in $x$ gives the picture above.

Comment: So.....?   If you have the equation $2x + 5 = 6$ and you plot $2x + 5$ you get an graph of a line, not the constant $6$ nor the value $x=0.5$.  You are being asked  to *solve* $f(x) = C$, that is to find the single point $x_0$ where $f(x_0) = C$. You are graphing *ALL* of $f(x)$ and expecting it to *always* equal $C$.  This is the same as being asked to solve $2x + 5 = 6$ and graphing $2x+5$ and expecting it to be $6$ everywhere.

Comment: @fleablood again your awesomeness!

Comment: This is a different thing. We have $f(x,y) = C$. So a solution $y=g(x)$ depends still on $x$. Thus $f(x,g(x))$ as a function should be constant $C$.

Comment: It may be the case that there are no solutions that are constant 1 in the region you marked red.

Comment: But I don't see a reason for this.

Comment: Consider $y=(1-x^2)/(x+a)^2$ (the $x-a$ case is similar). The expression under the square root is
$$1+\frac{(1-a^2)(1-x^2)}{(x+a)^2}=\frac{a^2x^2+2ax+1}{(x+a)^2}=\frac{(ax+1)^2}{(x+a)^2}$$ The square root of that is $\operatorname{abs}\left(\dfrac{ax+1}{x+a}\right)$; that is, it's $\pm\dfrac{ax+1}{x+a}$, using whichever sign makes the value non-negative, and *this depends upon $x$'s relationship to $a$ and $1$.* When the "$\pm$" is "$-$", the full left-hand-side expression reduces to $1$; when the "$\pm$" is "$+$", it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your simple calculus (but also Mathematica) did not keep track of all necessary conditions.

---

> If $0<a<1$ and $$\tag1\frac{x^2 (1+y)^2}{\left(a y + \sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}\right)^2} = 1,$$
>   solve for $y$ (as a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ of $x$).

To begin with, we must require $1+(1-a^2)y\ge 0$ and $ay+\sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}\ne0$. The first amounts to $y\ge-\frac 1{1-a^2}$, the latter to $y\ne -1$.

With this in mind, we solve the (then) equivalent
$$ x^2(1+y)^2=\left(ay+\sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}\right)^2.$$
We take square roots on both sides:
$$ |x|\cdot|1+y|=\left|ay+\sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}\right|$$
and begin by investigating one of two possible sign settings (the other being obtained by substituting $-x$ for $x$, so by a "horizontal flip" of the final result):
$$ x(1+y)=ay+\sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}$$
Take $ay$ to the left
$$ (x-a)y+x=\sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}$$
and square both sides:
$$ (x-a)^2y^2+2x(x-a)y+x^2 = 1+(1-a^2)y\qquad\color{red}{\text{and}\quad (x-a)y+x\ge 0}.$$
Ignore the red condition for the moment and rearrange as a standard quadratic in $y$:
$$ (x-a)^2y^2+((x-a)^2+x^2-1)y+(x^2-1)=0.$$
Instead of blindly applying the standard formula, observe that $y=-1$ is a solution (though one we excluded above) and after dividing by $y+1$, we arrive at 
$$(x-a)^2y+x^2-1=0 $$
and so

> no solution for $x=a\ne\pm1$

and otherwise 
$$ y=\frac{1-x^2}{(x-a)^2}.$$
The red condition amounts to 
$$ \frac{1-x^2}{x-a}+x\ge0$$
or after multiplication with $x-a$,
$$1-ax\ge 0\land x>a\qquad\text{or}\qquad 1-ax\le 0\land x<a. $$
Using $0<a<1$, we readily simplify this to $a<x\le\frac 1a$, i.e.,

> $y=\frac{1-x^2}{(x-a)^2}$ is a solution if $a<x\le\frac 1a$.

Together with the "horizontal flip" we summarize:

> If $a<x\le\frac1a$, then $y=\frac{1-x^2}{(x-a)^2}$ is the only solution. If $-\frac1a\le x<-a$, then $y=\frac{1-x^2}{(x+a)^2}$ is the only solution. For all other $x$, there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the red condition. (Maybe Mathematica as well.)

Answer (score 0):

In the original you have

$\frac{x^2 (1+y)^2}{\left(a y + \sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}\right)^2} = 1$

This restricts that $1+(1-a^2)y \ge 0$ so $y\ge -\frac 1{1-a^2}$

so when you solve

$y = \frac{1-x^2}{(x \pm a)^2}$

this restricts  $\frac {1-x^2}{(x\pm a)^2} \ge -\frac 1{1-a^2}$

Which probably would resitrict $x$ to a range.

However I get

so 
$(1-x^2)(1-a^2)\ge -(x\pm a)^2$

$-x^2(1-a^2) +(1-a^2) \ge - x^2 \mp 2ax - a^2$

$a^2x^2 \pm 2ax \ge -1$

$x(xa^2\pm 2a) \ge -1$

Which is unrestricted.

I suspect that there is some error in

$y = \frac{1-x^2}{(x \pm a)^2}$ (I don't see how you'd isolate the single power of $x$ in $(x \pm a)^2$) and with the correct solution there will be restrictions on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

In dashed blue we have for $a = \{0.1, 0.5, 0.9\}$ the trace for

$$ \frac{x^2 (1+y)^2}{\left(a y + \sqrt{1+(1-a^2)y}\right)^2} = 1$$

and also in red the trace for

$$
y = \frac{1-x^2}{(x \pm a)^2}.
$$

$$
a = 0.1
$$

[image]

$$
a = 0.5
$$

[image]

$$
a = 0.9
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you did: plug in the solutions in the original equation and try to simplify it. I got $1$. BUT you must consider that if you have something like $\sqrt{z^2}$ this could simplify to $z$ OR to $-z$, one of this won't work, but the other does.